# as.formula does not like equivalence '=' (object not found)

Tags: r, dataframe, formula

consider the following example

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(2,4,6));
transform(df1,c=a+b)
    a b c
  1 1 2 3
  2 2 4 6
  3 3 6 9
```

So far, so good. Now I would like to code this dynamically, using as.formula:

```
transform(df1,as.formula("c=a+b"))
```

However, R says

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'b' not found
```

This error does not occur using "~" as separator of left hand and right hand side. Can I somehow delay the evaluation of the formula? Is it possible at all to use as.formula on an assignment? I have tried fiddling around with 'with' but to no avail.

Comment: I think you want them to be `expression`s rather than formulae.  However, it looks like you're going to end up with some variation on `eval(parse(text="whatever"))`, which will lead to horrible, horrible code and hard to find bugs.  If possible, try and do something less clever.

Comment: It would be better to split up your character string across the equals sign.  On the left, you can so something like `df1[["c"]] <- something`.  Going from `"a+b"` to having that evaluated in `df1` means `eval(parse(text = "a+b"), df1)` or something equally ugly.  I suggest you tell us more about what you are trying to achieve so we can help think of an alternative.

Comment: In my real problem its not crucial to do it automatically, either. I just have about 50 columns, with names falling into the category "X[XOY][ABC]_[0-9][0-9]", eg "XXA_05". Now I would like to average over all columns of same "X[XOY]" type and same digits, eg "XXA_00" and "XXB_00" and save this to the first of these columns.

This can of course also be done on the column level by grepping the right columns. I just stumbled acroos the formula problem and wante to know if its possible at all to implement it as formula.

Comment: Don't use transform. It's a helper function suitable for interactive use, not for programming with.

Comment: Could you elaborate? So I should use eg df[[col1]]<-df[[col2]]+df[[col3]] instead of transform?

Comment: Also note the *caveat emptor* in the help file: If some of the values are not vectors of the appropriate length, you deserve whatever you get!

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the problem you mentioned in your comment, since that seems to be your real goal.  This avoids messing with the formulae from your original question.

A reproducible version of your dataset.

```
group_names <- apply(
    expand.grid("X", c("X", "O", "Y"), c("A", "B", "C"), "_", 0:9, 0:9),
    1,
    paste,
    collapse = ""
)
n_groups <- 50
n_points_per_group <- 10
df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(
    runif(n_points_per_group * n_groups),
    ncol = n_groups
))
colnames(df1) <- sample(group_names, n_groups)
```

Now convert the data frame to long format.  (Using `reshape` package here.  You could also use `stats::reshape`.)

```
melted_df1 <- melt(df1)
```

Define a grouping based upon your criteria that the second character and the number match.

```
melted_df1$group <- with(melted_df1, paste(
    substring(variable, 2, 2),    
    substring(variable, 5, 6),
    sep = ""
))
```

Now call `tapply` (or `plyr::ddply` if you prefer) to get the summary stats.

```
with(melted_df1, tapply(value, group, mean))
```