# Is it ok to use transform to add per row results of operation on data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I'm a bit confused. I routinely use transform like this

```
    ddply(data.frame, 1, transform, new.column = function(old.col.1,old.col.2,...))
```

This is also [recommended by Hadley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376219/adding-labels-to-data-with-ddply-while-subsetting/3379120#3379120).

But recently [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9094731/as-formula-does-not-like-equivalence-object-not-found) and Hadley stated this:

> Don't use transform. It's a helper function suitable for interactive use, not for programming with.

So whats wrong with transform? I think im convinced now that this is stupid:

```
   transform(data.frame,col2=fun(col1)).
```

But is it not very useful in the ddply setting?

Comment: Surely subset() should die the same death

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a difference between using `transform` within `ddply` and the function `transform()` as a standalone. It is far better (and quicker) to just do:

```
Mydata$col3 <- fun(Mydata$col1, Mydata$col2)
```

The function combination ddply/transform is especially useful if you have more than one column to change, eg

```
Mynewdata <- ddply(Mydata,1,transform,col3=fun1(col1,col2), col4=fun2(col1,col2))
```

And even then, you have the more flexible option of using `within()` that allows you to use calculated results to calculate the next row:

```
Mynewdata <- within(Mydata,{
    col2 <- fun1(col1)
    col3 <- fun2(col1,col2)
})
```

The thing with `transform()` is that it is especially written to be used interactively. If you use it within a function, you might run into trouble. It is similar to `subset()` in that way: They're convenience functions, but they're neither fast nor very safe to use within more complex code.

Opinions differ on `ddply()`. In some cases it works quick and gives very clean and readible code, in other cases I consider it serious overkill. `ddply()` often works faster and easier when you have to use non-vectorized functions, in which case the above options wouldn't work. But for that, you also have the option to use mapply:

```
Mynewdata <- within(Mydata, col3 <- mapply(myfun,col1,col2))
```

mapply can in this case also be quite faster. To give you a basic example:

```
Mydata <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(5),col2=rpois(5,3))
myfun <- function(x,y){
    if(y == 0) mean(x) else
     mean(c(x,seq(1,y,by=1)))
}

code1 <- expression(Newdata <- ddply(Mydata,1,transform,col3=myfun(col1,col2)))
code2 <- expression(Newdata2 <- within(Mydata, col3 <- mapply(myfun,col1,col2)))

> benchmark(code1,code2)
   test replications elapsed relative 
1 code1          100    0.50     12.5 
2 code2          100    0.04      1.0
```

The main problem I have with `ddply()` is that the order of your observations is not guaranteed, as you see in the example output below:

```
Mydata              Newdata2                    Newdata
        col1 col2         col1 col2      col3         col1 col2      col3
1 0.07060223    4 | 0.07060223    4 2.0141204 | 0.05658259    2 1.0188609
2 1.84645791    2 | 1.84645791    2 1.6154860 | 0.07060223    4 2.0141204
3 0.05658259    2 | 0.05658259    2 1.0188609 | 0.84119845    1 0.9205992
4 0.89998084    5 | 0.89998084    5 2.6499968 | 0.89998084    5 2.6499968
5 0.84119845    1 | 0.84119845    1 0.9205992 | 1.84645791    2 1.6154860
```

Both functions calculate the correct result, but `mapply()` does so faster **in this case** and with preserving the order of the observations in the dataframe.

Comment: Ok, but what about this command: 'ddply(data.frame, 1, transform, new.column = function(old.col.1,old.col.2,...))'? Is there a one-line alternative for doing exactly the same?

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer! I think the within-apply-solution would be a good replacement for ddply-transform. However, I'm not bothered so much by the sorting of ddply. It's a nuisance most of the time, but still the association of different data is not messed with - which would of course render ddply useless.

Comment: I too had this question, but I am still confused after reading your answer. My question was more along the lines of: are these two statements functionally equivalent? `ddply(data.frame, "var", transform, new.col=1/x)` and `transform(data.frame, new.col=1/x)`